# Homemade Vowelburgers™

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

They're simple Vowelburgers™, but they are great for munching on while watching TV.

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | LA |
| E | Ogre |
| I | Job |
| O | Marvel |
| U | Malibu |

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you for ordering a takeaway from Vowelburger™! Our recommended viewing for tonight is as follows:

> On Channel A = **RAM**. The [Los Angeles Rams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles_Rams) take on their close rivals in tonight's featured NFL game.
>
>  On Channel E = **REM**. Catch up on the latest instalments of anime series [Re:Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re:Zero_%E2%88%92_Starting_Life_in_Another_World_(season_1)). Is [Rem](https://rezero.fandom.com/wiki/Rem) the blue ogre? Why not [discuss this on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Re_Zero/comments/6uzxaj/discussion_ram_is_not_the_red_ogre_from_the_story/) while you watch.
>
>  On Channel I = **RIM**. Watch the 2016 TV movie, [*The Rim Job*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5847872/).
>
>  On Channel O = **ROM**. See what all the hype is about - watch the latest series from Marvel, featuring [Rom the Space Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rom_the_Space_Knight).
>
>  And at the same time, why not wash down your Vowelburgers™ with some [Malibu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malibu_(rum)) - i.e. some **RUM**!